# Concepts vs. legacy CRTP

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, crtp

I am about to refactor some C++ code containing the CRTP pattern to make use of the C++20 concepts.

The code (containing the desired but unused concept declaration) looks like this:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
concept Quackable = requires( T t ) { t.Quack(); };

template <typename T>
struct BaseDuck {
    void DoQuack() { Impl().Quack(); }
private:
    T& Impl() { return static_cast<T&>( *this ); }
};

struct Duck : public BaseDuck<Duck> {
    void Quack() const { std::cout << "quack"; }
};

int main() {
    Duck().DoQuack();
    return 0;
}
```

My first idea however was to constrain the type of `BaseDuck` which however does not succeed in compilation.

```cpp
template <Quackable T>
struct BaseDuck {
    void DoQuack() { Impl().Quack(); }
private:
    T& Impl() { return static_cast<T&>( *this ); }
};
```

It works when changing to

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct BaseDuck {
    void DoQuack() requires Quackable<T> { Impl().Quack(); }
private:
    T& Impl() requires Quackable<T> { return static_cast<T&>( *this ); }
};
```

Is the good enough or should the CRTP pattern also be refactored/removed to gain static polymorphism of modern C++?

Comment: I'm confused about the intention of your API. We have a base class called `BaseDuck`, and then an interface(?) that derives from it called `IDuck`, and then `DuckLike<T>` which implements the interface by taking the default implementation from the base and defining a *new* method `DoQuack` that delegates to its own `Quack` while ignoring its type argument. Then `Duck` implements `DuckLike<Duck>` and has no body. What is the gain of all of this type-level chicanery?

Comment: You're trying to constraint `DuckLike` by a condition that itself (indirectly) depends on `DuckLike`. GCC is pretty clear: `the required expression 't.Quack()' is invalid, because ... 't' has incomplete type`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I left out all irrelant members and methods of the classes. So never mind the inheritance and names.

Comment: @tbeu If we disregard the code you've shown us, what do we then have to go on? Please fix your code to clearly show your intent.

Comment: One way to get rid of CRTP is to use [deducing this](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html) instead.  You can probably then constrain what type `this` can point to.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I update the example code to hopefully better show the intent.

Comment: @tbeu It's much clearer now so +1 - I would say that the workaround is _not_ good enough since you can still instantiate a `Duck` which isn't `Quackable` just as long as you don't try to make it quack since the member functions have been disabled. I don't have a solution in mind for the interesting problem right now though.

Comment: Fixing so that it doesn't compile when you try to instantiate a `Duck` that can't quack can be done with a `static_assert(Quackable<T>);` in a constructor (that is always used). However, a good solution wouldn't even let it compile even if you don't try to instantiate a quackless `Duck`.